# Пропадает значения глобальных переменных внутри функции в конструкции if else

Tags: javascript, функции, if

```
var i = 0;
var z = i + 1;
console.log(toppx);
var topx = marginUp(z, toppx);

function marginUp(z, toppx) {
    if (z == 1) {
        console.log(toppx);
        console.log(z);
        return  topx = toppx + 'px';
    } else if (z => 2) {
        return topx = -toppx + 'px';
    }
}
console.log(topx);
```

Comment: А вы сами понимаете, что написали? присваиваете переменной `topx ` что ? Результат выполнения функции `marginUp`. Может стоит тогда `marginUp` отдельно вызвать, как минимум? Притом функция ожидает на вход получить что-то, а ничего не передаете. Не кажется вам это странным?  А где объявленная `toppx`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Внутри функции переменная toppx локальна, т.е. это будет ровно то, что вы туда передадите 2м агрументом. Если прям сильно нужно достучаться до toppx внутри функции - в объявлении функции обзовите 2й аргумент по другому.

Значения 2х аргументов внутри функции отсутствуют, потому что при вызове, вы их не передаете, соответственно они будут undefined.

А значение переменной topx вы просто затираете. Если вы что-то ожидаете из функии - используйте оператор return. Без него возврат будет в неявном виде со значением undefined

Comment: спасибо разобрался, исправил

Answer (score 2):

Вы если объявляете функцию с двумя параметрами

```
function marginUp(z, toppx) {
```

то и передавайте ей две переменные при вызове

```
var topx = marginUp(???);
```

А если вы хотите использовать глобальные переменные, то не нужно указывать параметры в объявлении функции, да еще с названиями переменных из глобальной области видимости.

**P.S.** А это

```
console.log(topx); //undefined
```

из-за того, что ваша функция ни чего не возвращает вот тут

```
var topx = marginUp();
```

**P.P.S** Еще одна ошибка замеченная @LEQADA

```
if (z = 1)
```

Это не сравнение переменной `z` с `1`, это присвоение, `z` становится равной `1`.

Сравнение выглядит так

```
if (z == 1)
```

Comment: Не могли бы вы добавить к ответу замечание по поводу несуществующего оператора сравнения `if (z = 1) {`?

Comment: @LEQADA, спасибо!

Comment: спасибо разобрался, исправил